# Constructor cannot call itself

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I use Castle Windsor for the DI mechanism, and I'm stuck here. I use the constructor injection type which works fine.

But, when I declare some other class's constructor, I need to invoke the default constructor, where the DI magic takes place.

So, I have the following code:

```
private readonly IUserService UserService = null;

public CustomAccessAttribute(IUserService userService)
{
    this.UserService = userService;
}

public CustomAccessAttribute(bool someParam) : this() //here I'd like to call the above constructor
{
    ....           
}
```

but I get the error

> Constructor 'CustomAccessAttribute.CustomAccessAttribute(bool)' cannot call itself

I don't want to put the `userService` object by myself inside of the `this()` call, because the DI container should do this. So, how can I fix that error?

Comment: Where is your parameterless constructor?

Comment: Do you have a default constructor? Otherwise, `this()` wont work.

Comment: 'Invoke the default constructor where the DI magic takes place' what does that mean? DI magic cannot possibly happen on a default constructor

Comment: *when I declare some other class's constructor, I need to invoke the default constructor, where the DI magic takes place.* This makes no sense. You need not invoke any default constructor youself. Do clarify what you mean.

Comment: No Magic happens in the default ctor under the definition of ctor injection... I think you're confusing the term. More code would be required to know exactly how

Comment: The constructor overload you're choosing is dictated by the call signature. Once the code is compiled, there's no way for the DI to somehow change what constructor your call resolves to. If you want to call a constructor that accepts an `IUserService`, you need to provide one, or let the DI do so. The DI can't hold your other constructors hand *after* it's been invoked.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're attacking this in the wrong way.

If you want the DI container to choose the right overload, you must provide all the arguments you want to receive. Accepting a `bool` only won't help, since you actually need the `IUserService` interface as well. It won't make itself appear out of nowhere. Your DI needs to know that it exists and it must be passed to appropriate constructor.

What you need is:

```
private readonly IUserService UserService = null;
public CustomAccessAttribute(IUserService userService)
{
    this.UserService = userService;
}

public CustomAccessAttribute(IUserService userService, bool someParam) : this(userService) 
{         
}
```

Although, you usually want to make the constructor chaining outwards, from the least parameters to the most. So perhaps you'd want to do:

```
private readonly IUserService UserService = null;
public CustomAccessAttribute(IUserService userService) : this(userService, false)
{
}

public CustomAccessAttribute(IUserService userService, bool someParam)
{  
    this.UserService = userService;
}
```

**Edit:**

If the `bool` you want to pass to your constructor isn't available at injection time, then constructor injection is probably not the way to go at all. Perhaps a more suitable way would be to set it as a property, which could be set once that `bool` is available, or a factory pattern which will create the class instance for you when everything is available.

Comment: I don't think this will work for OP's case. It seems unlikely the DI will be able to provide a reasonable value for `someParam`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I don't see why not. He'll simply need to configure the `bool` parameter to be passed when the class is injected. If the `bool` isn't available at that time, then perhaps he'll need to consider other ways of accepting it which aren't the class constructor.

Comment: Something like a `bool` param is not a service. You typically provide simple types like this to configure behavior, not inject encapsulated functionality into a class. As a result, they probably need to provide different values at different places in the code, rather than being able to make a registration with the DI.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I agree that a `bool` is something that will usually vary during run-time. But as the OP didn't specify what it is, and it could infact not even be a `bool` (perhaps OP just created it as a simple example), I can't know. OP should clarify.

Comment: OP should not be using DI on his attributes in the first place, and if he's got to specify data at resolve-time his best bet is to register a factory with the container, and inject that to whoever is specifying the bool

Comment: @CallumBradbury Which attributes are you talking about?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The CustomAccessAttribute, I'm taking a leap of faith that it's an actual attribute and not just a weirdly named class

Comment: @CallumBradbury Oh, didn't even notice that. Hoping you're right :) But, he says it works for him in the first case, and attributes can only be provided with compile-time values, so I'm assuming it really *isn't* an attribute derivative.

Comment: Yeah I hope it isn't an attribute, it is technically possible to DI them but at that point it is true wizardry that I don't believe the OP is capable of. I think the correct answer to his query is a factory pattern, there's no other way (that I know of) to reliably specify someParam differently for each new instance, without getting a massive headache.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confused as to how IoC works. When you want to create an instance of a class there is no 'Magic' that happens to pass the parameters in, and if you new up an instance of your CustomAccessAttribute manually, Windsor will have nothing to do with it as it won't know you're creating an instance. Windsor (usually) follows the following steps:

1. You register your implementation of IUserService with your container
2. You call myContainer.Resolve<CustomAccessAttribute>() (or resolve something with CustomAccessAttribute as a dependency)
3. Your container looks at CustomAccessAttribute and sees that the constructor takes an IUserService
4. Your container builds an implementation of IUserService and passes it into the constructor, then returns the new CustomAccessAttribute to you (or whoever needed it injecting)

None of these steps require any 'Magic', but they all require you to be interacting with the container itself, not just newing up instances and relying on DI Magic.

If you create a default constructor without the IUserService being passed in, you'll find that the IUserService one will be resolved anyway if you're using Resolve(), as Windsor will always resolve the constructor with the most parameters that it has registered implementations for.

The real question is why an attribute needs an IUserService in the first place, when they should only be used for metadata, not behaviour. I don't even think Windsor will happily resolve attributes without a bunch of extra setup, which hints at what a bad idea it is.

Comment: This is probably due to the horrible design of Asp.Net Mvc which encourages behavior in attributes